# JCenter throwing 409 for Play Services

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, jcenter

I have been trying to import an android project today but it never finishes. Gradle keeps complaining about

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.4.2/play-services-base-11.4.2.pom'. Received status code 409 from server:
```

I tried following the URL in the log, which redirects to https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.4.2/play-services-base-11.4.2.pom
which then gives the below response.

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 409,
    "message" : "Failed to read POM for 'com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/11.4.2/play-services-base-11.4.2.pom': expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</dependencies>\\n \\ua0<l... @30:5) ."
  } ]
}
```

I am at a loss for what to do. Why is this happening and what can I do to solve this?

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.testfairy.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.testfairy.plugins.gradle:testfairy:1.12'
        classpath 'org.moallemi.gradle.advanced-build-version:gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
        classpath "net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:gradle-plugin:0.11.+"
//        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.5.5'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.8.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'testfairy'
apply plugin: 'org.moallemi.advanced-build-version'
apply plugin: "build-time-tracker"
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dexcount {
    format = "list"
    includeClasses = false
    includeFieldCount = true
    includeTotalMethodCount = true
    orderByMethodCount = true
    verbose = false
    maxTreeDepth = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    teamCityIntegration = false
//    enableForInstantRun = false
}

advancedVersioning {
    nameOptions {
        versionMajor 1
        versionMinor 11
        versionPatch new Date().format('yyMMdd') as int
        versionBuild versionCode
    }
    codeOptions {
        versionCodeType org.moallemi.gradle.internal.VersionCodeType.DATE
        //dependsOnTasks 'testfairy', 'release' //, 'assemble'
    }
    outputOptions {
        renameOutput true
        nameFormat '$projectName-$buildType-$versionName'
    }
}

android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'png', 'wav'
    }
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx"
//        testApplicationId "com.airbeem.airbeemsimulator"
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode advancedVersioning.versionCode //67
        versionName advancedVersioning.versionName //"4.10-${new Date().format('yyMMdd')}"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
        debug.initWith(signingConfigs.release)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }

    testfairyConfig {
        apiKey "xxx"
        iconWatermark true
        testersGroups "android"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':xxx')
}

buildtimetracker {
    reporters {
        summary {
            ordered false
            threshold 50
            barstyle "unicode"
        }
    }
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem!

Comment: Could you post your Gradle config? Google Play services SDK components have never been hosted on jcenter(). Previously they were delivered as part of the Android Studio SDK manager, and since last year have been offered from maven.google.com (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven)

Comment: @ZhiQiao I have added the gradle files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, got it. Go to your *top-level gradle file* and make sure that everywhere you have a `repositories` clause, that `google()` is the first repo.

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    ... etc ...
}
```

I'm not really sure why this one hit suddenly, but moving the Google repo to the top fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem,which was sloved by deleting maven url as below.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/